# Apache 2.2.19 release compatible with tomcat 6?

Tags: apache, mod-jk

We have apache 2.2.14 but need to upgrade to a higher version due to security vulnerabilities. Apache 2.2.19 is the highest and available now, but we are not sure if it will be compatible with Tomcat 6 we are having. How can I find out about the compatibilities & possible risks? and will it be compatible with tomcat 7?

Comment: What are you using to talk between them?  mod_proxy?  mod_jk?

Answer (score 0):

Nobody will guarantee you 100% absence of any issues when upgrading, but then there is little chance of anything breaking when just hopping a few steps in the 2.2 line. It also depends on how you proxy to Tomcat, only AJP (mod_jk) integrates tighter with it, *slightly* raising the probability of *possible but unlikely* issues.

In the end, if you're worried, it's a matter of reading the changelogs. The "just try" approach works too, in the assumption you have a proper testing/QA stage.